# Purchasing questions

Tags: discussion, scope, questions, question-appropriateness

Are purchasing recommendations allowable?

Here's an example:

Joe wants a new Android 3 tablet. He asks a question that says:

*I'm in the market for a new Android 3 tablet. I want one with a 1GHz processor, a Gorilla Glass screen, a camera on the front, and it should have internal GPS.*

How would you respond to Joe? Why?

I see [this answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here/249#249) says 'No!', but I still see questions like this that have not been downvoted nor closed by a moderator.

More specifically, what types of purchasing recommendations are allowable? E.G. 'I want an X with Y, where would I find one?' or 'I want a cheap X, recommend me something' or 'I think X is a nice phone, but are there any cheap alternatives?'

Comment: If you're seeing questions like this, please flag them. Moderators can't be everywhere.

Comment: And if you want to ask a question like this, try [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25/android)!

Answer (score 9):

Covered here

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

but the TL;DR version is:

> Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach him how to fish and he can eat forever.

That is, *teach people how to evaluate android hardware* -- don't spoon feed them specific recommendations that will be obsolete in 12 months.

Comment: I think the more accurate quote is "Give a man a fish and he will eat for a day. Teach him how to fish and he will sit on a boat and drink beer all day."