# Are questions looking for apps on topic? As in: "I need an app that does XYZ?" or "I want a widget that does ABC"

Tags: discussion, questions, faq-proposed

The [FAQ](https://android.stackexchange.com/faq) doesn't currently discuss shopping.   In the faq question: [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here) there is an [answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-not-ask-here/249#249) that says that shopping recommendations are not allowed, but that app recommendations are "on the border".

Are these on topic: I need an app that does XYZ? or I want a widget that does ABC.

Comment: See also: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/31/is-what-is-an-app-that-does-x-y-and-z-a-valid-question

Answer (score 7):

I like what Al said over [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-ask-here/252#252):

> Some completely made up example
>   titles:
>
> ```
> * How can I stop certain apps from starting automatically? Should I?
> * How can I export my contacts to a CSV file?
> * How can I get my Calendar app to start the week on a Monday?
> * How can I send a single SMS message to multiple recipients?
> * How do I root my Android device? Why would I want to?
> ```
>
> I guess the key here is if you can't
>   phrase it as "How can/do I do X on my
>   device (in this app)?" it's suspect.

So basically, don't ask "What's the best music player" (very subjective) but "[How can I play gapless music](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6497/which-apps-do-gapless-music-playback)" instead.  The former is way too subjective and differs on opinion whereas we can actually answer the latter question.

Comment: Precise and to the point. This should be linked to / included with the FAQ IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Such questions should be posted here instead:

Software Recommendations
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/