# Closure: 'How can I download directions for public transport (bus, subway) offline?'

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Why was [my question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/161156/183893) (whose title I rewrote 2 minutes ago) closed as 'off-topic', when it resembles [these others](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/offline?sort=votes&pageSize=15) that were resolved by users' suggestions of apps?

Comment: This question and answer may be helpful: [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a product?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1289/267)

Answer (score 5):

I was one of the close voters.

- You were **specifically** seeking for an *app*, which is discouraged for reasons mentioned and reproduced

> Questions asking us to find or recommend an app, device, ROM, accessory or off-site resource are off-topic for Android Enthusiasts as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam and become obsolete quickly

- Asking for a *way or means* to achieve your aim, is *broader* and covers  *all approaches*  to solve ( apps inclusive but  barring programming / ROM modding, etc) .
- If the intent of OP is to specifically seek an app based solution, then [SE Softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is the right place. Here it is about posing a problem and asking for solutions, and those who respond may well offer app based solution or something in addition to app . See [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/160254/131553) for example. It was also voted for closure but edited by me to make it a *non app* seeking question and answered  . OP now has a method to help him  involving a hybrid approach of using an app and other means resulting in a *win - win* outcome for the OP and the site
- There are older questions on the site, which seek apps specifically and have not been closed. My *guess* is that these pre-date the current policy

Related [Are questions looking for apps on topic? As in: "I need an app that does XYZ?" or "I want a widget that does ABC"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/353/131553)

**Edit:** To sum up , questions *on this site* are liable to be closed if they specifically seek *app based* solutions, whereas solutions can include app based approach

Comment: Yes, we definitely got a lot of "offline maps" questions early on in the site.  If any that are still around are off-topic, please flag them and we can close or lock them.