# Why are you so rigorous and why we have so many questions closed

Tags: support, close-reasons, new-users

Firs at all I like android enthusiasts very much,
I am kinda scared that if you keep going like this, you are going to close this site.

My questions are :
Why do you so often closing questions ?
Does you have statistics to compare how many questions has been closed here and at others sites ?
If I take a look at my profile at Stackoverflow there is 54 questions and only 2 closed, at serverfault I have 35 questions with 2 closing at superuser I have 6 question and one moved to serverfault.  Here on android I have 8 questions with 4 closes.
Is this case only for me or there is others who having same situation with high frequency closing questions ?

Answer (score 10):

I don't think I've yet seen a question closed that didn't have a legitimate reason to be closed. If you feel like many of your questions are being closed then you might just want to re-read the FAQ and some of the Meta topics so that you know what is considered appropriate for AE and what is not. Closing questions is an important part of keeping the site clean and organized, and isn't necessarily a bad sign, but an indicator that the higher-rep users are involved.

I would also say that we get a large number of development questions due to the word "Android" in the title of the site, and they are all subsequently closed and moved to SO. I have no data to go along with that statement, but it seems to happen pretty frequently.

When the site is in beta there is a lot of onus on the high-rep users and mods to make sure that the rules are enforced, since it's a time period that will define the site later on down the road. Perhaps this encourages people to use their votes, but again, I don't (personally) feel that any questions are being closed without reasonable cause.

That being said, I also only see one closed question on your account on AE, though perhaps you have others that were deleted which I cannot view. The one that I can still see was very clearly 1) A shopping recommendation, which is decidedly off-topic and 2) A fairly subjective comparison of two devices.

Answer (score 6):

Having been a StackOverflow moderator for the past few weeks, I can tell you that the Android tag probably has a higher percentage of closed questions than any other tag (mostly as "Not a Real Question").

I'll leave the question of *why that is the case* as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what eldarerathis said (with which I fully agree):

I believe we're about to be graduated out of beta, so I don't think you need to be worried about the site closing.

But beyond that, StackOverflow expects objective questions about programming problems.  Looking at your questions there, they fit very well.  Here, we expect objective questions about using the Android operating system.  **All** of your questions here are either "Can you do X on Android" which you should mostly be Googling, or entirely subjective questions like "Must-have apps", "How can we help visually impaired users", "Which protocol should I use for NAS", etc.  None of them are good questions.

For help forming good questions, see [FAQ: "What kind of questions should I ask here?"](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246/faq-what-kind-of-questions-should-i-ask-here/)